# Event Handler creation support missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm developing with Visual Studio 2017 a WebForm Asp.Net web application.

it's a couple of days that the event handler autocomplete doesn't work anymore:

Previously, after I've added a control on the page, I was able to type the name of the event, *OnClick* in example, and then by typing the **="** Visual studio shows me a drop down with the **"create new..."** and the list of the compatible handlers for the event.

The "create new..." feature is quite fundamental to me as I don't always know the signature of the method, and overall I don't have to write it by hand.

All these tasks were performed in the source view of the aspx page, and the event handler method was inserted automatically by Visual Studio in the aspx.cs file.

For example, on a button control, by selecting the **"Create New..."** item in the event handlers suggestions, VS automatically create the following code in aspx.cs:

```
protected void BtnDoSomething_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

**Now the drop-down suggestions are not shown anymore.**

The project compiles successfully.
I've tried to restart the project, restart VS, restart the PC, open an old project... nothing has worked.

What can I do to bring it back?

Comment: Had the same problem with WPF; When I have an error or unsolved warning, in the same file intellisense does not work.

Comment: What version of VS 2017 are you on? Check this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/162953/vs-17-155-intellisense-not-working.html

Comment: But I don't have any error or warning in the file/project. I'm running 15.5.2, no I can't believe there's a bug on this...I can't develop anymore without it they must find a solution in the next hours!!

Comment: There are always bugs in new products. I'm still on VS 2015 and staying on it until well into the service pack cycle of 2017 version. Go to the MS connect site and check on the status of this particular issue  - maybe there is a fix. Either way, this is not a "showstopper".

Comment: The error/warning could be in the .aspx.cs/.aspx page. Check both! You can create a fresh project and check the intellisense before/after adding your control (or your pieces one by one). At the end you'll find what hangs the intellisense.

Comment: @BassemAkl no error/warning at all in the whole project. How can I debug the intellisense?

Comment: Simply Google the signature of the event handler you need?

Comment: @IrishChieftain Are you joking??! ;) I've deadlines on projects, and I cant lose seconds/minutes for finding signatures of asp.net and third-party controls!

Comment: Takes about ten seconds... I think you need a little perspective here. If I can't recall the signature of a handler for, say, a ListView event, I can find it instantly by Googling the MSDN docs.

Comment: FYI, Connect is being retired and they are now using "Collaborate". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/collaborate/connect-redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also upgrading Visual Studio to **15.6.3** has not solved the issue.
I've tried also the following:

1. Uncheck option "Allow parallel project initialization" (Tools >
   Options > Projects and Solutions > General)
2. Delete .vs folder in the project solution folder
3. Restart Visual Studio
4. Disable all extensions, one by one and restart VS

**None of the above has worked.**

I've noticed that inside a new blank page in the same project the intellisense was working fine.
After some debug I've found that the attribute "style" of some elements in the page was causing the issue:

```
<div style="display:none"></div>
```

**By removing all the style attribs from the .aspx page solved the issue**.

By adding back again also one of it cause the intellisense stop to work.
It's not really an issue as I use style only for fast&quick test, so I'll avoid them, but **Does anyone know why?!?**

Comment: I do not want to repeat my comment again. But I've to: Check the styles of these elements and their basic/parent style. For sure there is some error there, even if it is not reported in the error/warning window.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm running VS2017 15.5.6 and have the same problem with a Webforms application. My workaround is to temporary delete most of the code from markup (saving it in Notepad), leaving only the controls directly surrounding and including the control that needs the event handler itself, then add the event handler, which than succeeds, and add the removed code back again. Although there might be some hidden errors in my code, I’m unable to find them and there are no warnings or errors mentioned. But this particular page is rather large: 600 lines in markup and 1932 lines in code behind. Markup contains about 500 controls.

**Edit:**
I've updated to version 15.7.3: the problem still exists

Comment: Thanks PaulvdElst, if anyone will find a solution please let's update this post!

Comment: I was running Visual Studio 2017 on Windows Server 2016. I've taken the step to switch over to Windows 10 (I'm still running Visual Studio 15.7.3). Now the problem is gone: the event handlers gets created normally and IntelliSense (e.g. expanding event handler create or choose existing) is working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Check your

```
CodeBehind="yourwebpagename.aspx.cs"
```

at the top of the page.

Comment: that would be nice if you include screenshot or be more explicit on what page.